# How to configure to EC2 event to a java-lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I would like to write a lambda function in java so that whenever a particular folder on an EC2 instance is updated with a new file, I need to get that file and upload it to an S3 bucket. Can I do that? What is the appropriate event to handle in the lambda function ? Any example ? Thanks in advance. - Ramesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Lambda can't be triggered directly from a file appearing in a folder on an EC2 instance. Look at `inotifywait` or equivalent. Run that on the EC2 instance and respond to files appearing by syncing them to S3.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod for the confirmation.